# Emacs electric-pair-mode disable specific pairs

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am using `electric-pair-mode` in `org-mode` with `org-tempo`, and so I would like to tell `electric-pair-mode` not to act on angle brackets `<` and `>` any longer.

Otherwise it messes up the template expansion of `org-tempo`. Two things are getting in the way: (1) For every opening `<`, it automatically adds the `>`; (2) When a region is active and I type `<`, it puts the `<` and `>` around that region and de-activates the region, preventing `org-tempo` from properly acting on that region.

How can I define a hook for `org-mode` that tells `electric-pair-mode` to stop treating angle brackets as pairs (but otherwise remain fully functional)?

Thanks for your help,

HPF

Comment: I believe this will help you https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26225/dont-pair-quotes-in-electric-pair-mode (setup `electric-pair-inhibit-predicate` to ignore `<` in org-mode buffers)

Comment: I think this question should be moved to https://emacs.stackexachange.com, but I can't flag it as such.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks, the `inhibit-predicate` did the trick. I now use the following hook in my `.emacs` file:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda ()
           (setq-local electric-pair-inhibit-predicate
                   `(lambda (c)
                  (if (char-equal c ?<) t (,electric-pair-inhibit-predicate c))))))
```